# Dialog failure after deployment

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I have deployed a solution in production and since then, a specific dialog is not working correctly. In the solution I have imported in production, that dialog does exist but I have not modified it. Only added a few other workflows to it and when I deployed, I chose to overwrite all customization in the target environment (production).

For some reasons, security roles were modified even though they were not part of the solution (?). Since then, we fixed the roles so our workflows/dialogs would work again but we are still having an issue with one dialog.

Here is the log file:

```
>Crm Exception: Message: SecLib::AccessCheckEx failed. Returned hr = -2147187962, ObjectID: 3732d599-343b-e211-ada4-0050569512fe, OwnerId: 8a3819fd-333b-e211-ada4-0050569512fe,  OwnerIdType: 9 and CallingUser: a6e65698-daa2-e211-bd17-0050569512fe. ObjectTypeCode: 2020, objectBusinessUnitId: 765d6665-293b-e211-ada4-0050569512fe, AccessRights: ReadAccess , ErrorCode: -2147187962
[2014-04-15 08:28:37.797] Process: w3wp |Organization:f6ff335a-293b-e211-ada4-0050569512fe |Thread:   13 |Category: Platform.Sdk |User: a094a9a1-29f2-4079-972c-b682b966825c |Level: Error |ReqId: 85a8444a-bcd0-4de6-ada5-30e8eea8a142 | VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute  ilOffset = 0x65
>Web Service Plug-in failed in SdkMessageProcessingStepId: {CFCBBB1B-EA3E-DB11-86A7-000A3A5473E8}; EntityName: queueitem; Stage: 30; MessageName: Retrieve; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
Inner Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmSecurityException: SecLib::AccessCheckEx failed. Returned hr = -2147187962, ObjectID: 3732d599-343b-e211-ada4-0050569512fe, OwnerId: 8a3819fd-333b-e211-ada4-0050569512fe,  OwnerIdType: 9 and CallingUser: a6e65698-daa2-e211-bd17-0050569512fe. ObjectTypeCode: 2020, objectBusinessUnitId: 765d6665-293b-e211-ada4-0050569512fe, AccessRights: ReadAccess 
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.SecurityLibrary.AccessCheckEx2(ExecutionContext context, SecurityPrincipal principal, SecurityPrincipal ownerPrincipal, Guid objectId, Int32 objectTypeCode, Guid objectBusinessUnitId, AccessRights rights)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.SecurityLibrary.AccessCheckEx(ExecutionContext context, SecurityPrincipal ownerPrincipal, Guid objectId, Int32 objectTypeCode, Guid objectBusinessUnitId, AccessRights rights)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.SecurityLibrary.AccessCheckEx(ExecutionContext context, SecurityAttributes attributes, AccessRights rights)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.SecurityExtension.PostRetrieveHandler(Object sender, ExtensionEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Retrieve(BusinessEntityMoniker moniker, EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context, Int32 languageCode, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Retrieve(BusinessEntityMoniker moniker, EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context, Int32 languageCode)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.Retrieve(BusinessEntityMoniker moniker, EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)
```

I have tried to get more information about the `SdkMessageProcessingStepId` with ID `CFCBBB1B-EA3E-DB11-86A7-000A3A5473E8` but I can't find anything in the tables.

I have made sure the role of the user has proper access to `ObjectTypeCode` of `2020` and this by the way, works fine in another environment (TEST).

Sorry for the formatting, I have done my best to make it readable.

Comment: Can you say what code you have in plugin for retrieving of queueitem?

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with this CRM solution. I was trying to get more information using the ID of the SdkMessageProcessingStepId mentioned. I queried the SQL tables directly and found no record with this ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear:

> SecLib::AccessCheckEx failed

this means a permission error

> ObjectTypeCode: 2020

the entity involved, in this case `Queue`

> AccessRights: ReadAccess

missing privilege, in this case Read

> CallingUser: a6e65698-daa2-e211-bd17-0050569512fe

The user id that is missing this privilege.

Comment: I can see that. But the Read privilege is set to "User" in both environments for the security role users are part of. Works in one, but not in production, the other.

Comment: the owner of the record is a team, are you sure the "user" privilege is enough for that user to access that record? did you try to elevate the privilege?

Comment: Right, owner type ID 9 is indeed a Team. Maybe I should check if that Team has enough Read access to Queue record and that the user is part of that team?

Comment: I will try to elevate the read privilege for the user first, just to confirm that is a privilege issue. Probably the user is not part of that team, but if need to be inside that team or not depends on your organization structure

Comment: Turns out the user needed to be part of that team. Thanks.